# How to calculate volume fraction from the fugacity?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, field-theory, lattice-model

1:1 electrolytes is in a lattice whose each volume is $a^{3}$. The number of positive and negative particle is $N_{\pm} = N/2$.

From the grand canonical partition function, we can calculate $N_{\pm} = \frac{1}{Z}\frac{\partial Z}{\partial \beta\mu_{\pm}}$, where $\mu_{\pm}$ is a chemical potential. We also define fugacity $\lambda_{\pm} = e^{\beta\mu_{\pm}}$

Let's define volume fraction $\phi_{0}=Na^{3}/V=2c_{b}/V$, where $c_{b}$ is the bulk concentration of the electrolyte and $V$ is the total volume.

In the thermodynamic limit $N, V \rightarrow \infty$ while $c_{b}$ and $\phi_{0}$ remain finite.

Then, how the chemical potential can be expressed as

$e^{\beta\mu_{+}} = e^{\beta\mu_{-}} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\phi_{0}}{1-\phi_{0}}$,

where we assumed that the chemical potentials of the positive and negative ions are equal.